# Reusable nav link with icon component in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade, tailwind-css

I'm working on an admin interface using Laravel, AlpineJS and Tailwind CSS and I'm currently building the sidebar which can have many links, each link having an icon. I created a general `x-sidebar-link` component and a distinct component for each icon, but I'm not really fond of the approach because I can't really use those icon components elsewhere.

Is there a better way to build this in order to ensure reusability of the icon component? Like to be able to pass in classes for the active state as well, if needed.

The `x-sidebar-link` component:

```
@props(['active'])

@php
    $classes = ($active ?? false)
                ? 'bg-gray-100 text-gray-900 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md'
                : 'text-gray-600 hover:bg-gray-50 hover:text-gray-900 group flex items-center px-2 py-2 text-sm font-medium rounded-md';
@endphp

<a {{ $attributes->merge(['href' => '#', 'class' => $classes]) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</a>
```

The `x-icons.dashboard` component:

```
@aware(['active' => false])

@php
    $classes = ($active ?? false)
               ? 'text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6'
               : 'text-gray-400 group-hover:text-gray-500 mr-3 flex-shrink-0 h-6 w-6';
@endphp

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"
     aria-hidden="true" {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => $classes]) }}>
    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2"
          d="M3 12l2-2m0 0l7-7 7 7M5 10v10a1 1 0 001 1h3m10-11l2 2m-2-2v10a1 1 0 01-1 1h-3m-6 0a1 1 0 001-1v-4a1 1 0 011-1h2a1 1 0 011 1v4a1 1 0 001 1m-6 0h6"/>
</svg>
```

The way I'm using these is as following:

```
<nav>
    <x-sidebar-link :href="route('dashboard')" :active="request()->routeIs('dashboard')">
        <x-icons.dashboard />
        Dashboard
    </x-sidebar-link>

    <x-sidebar-link :href="route('profile')" :active="request()->routeIs('profile')">
        <x-icons.profile />
        Profile
    </x-sidebar-link>
    ...
</nav>
```

Comment: did you watch https://youtu.be/0Rq-yHAwYjQ?t=24286

Comment: I know about Caleb's talk and taking icon as a prop with the help of a dynamic component, but I don't see how that solves the issue of being able to manage active state classes.

Comment: but you have not actually stated that 'active state classes' is the problem?  Why does your icon component not work standalone?

Comment: By `ensure reusability of the icon component` I was thinking about being more flexible in terms of classes for both states, active and inactive. It works as a standalone, sure, but if I want to use it somewhere else where an active state is required, I don't have a way to provide the corresponding classes.

Comment: I updated the post now in order to make that clear.